# Find the expected value of the observation at time T+1 in HMM

Tags: expected-value, hidden-markov-model

I have built a HMM model in R using `depmixs4` package. I have the state projections and posterior probabilities till time T. I understand that to find the state projections for time T+1, I have to multiply the transition matrix with the posterior from time T.

But how can I find the expected value of the observation at time T+1, I don't know how to get the emission matrix since only the transition matrix is given in the output.

I am new to HMM, just starting to learn. So would appreciate any help.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130295/can-hidden-markov-models-be-used-to-predict-next-observation might help